# Issues with PythonPath: ImportError or Segmentation Fault

Tags: python, opencv

I was having some trouble using OpenCV on my computer. I had an old version of OpenCV that was working, but it seemed to be missing some library files. So I removed it, and installed the newest OpenCV.

When I tried to run the samples, I got the message: "ImportError: No module named cv". I tried to import it manually, and I would get the same error.

I remember having a similar issue when I was using Snow Leopard and an older version of OpenCV (I am now using Mavericks and Python 2.7.6). I changed the PythonPath in my .bash_profile, and it worked after that.

I went back to my .bash_profile and found that I had left the PythonPath as the old path. So I changed it to

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Users/santosh/opencv-2.4.7/build/lib:$PYTHONPATH
```

When I did this, I am now getting a "Segmentation Fault: 11" when I run python scripts.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: How are you installing opencv?